# generic variable declaration

Tags: c#, generics

I am not sure if this can be accomplished at all but here is my question.

Using C#, is it possible to declare a generic or non-typed variable but later in my code specify what that variable should be?

```
object genericObject;

if (!testFlag)
{
    genericObject = new SpecificObject1();
}

if (testFlag)
{
    genericObject = new SpecificObject2();
}

genericObject.FirstName = "Samuel";
genericObject.LastName = "Jackson";
```

I am hoping that after the "if logic" I can now call the similar methods each "specific" object had in common.

So is it possible to create some form of generic object in the beginning of my code and instantiate the specific object I want to use later?

Maybe there is a design pattern or refactoring effort that needs to be considered here as well.

Comment: That seems to beg for an interface

Comment: Maybe the Factory Design Pattern? http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/469453/Illustrating-Factory-pattern-with-a-very-basic-exa

Comment: I suppose that you can do something to this effect with the c# reflection library which allows you to enumerate over the different methods and properties of a particular type

Comment: @HanletEscaño how's that going to help on the call site?

Comment: @RuneFS he asked if there could be a design pattern, and I think the Factory fits his needs.

Comment: @HanletEscaño and I asked how the design pattern helps solve a type theoretic problem. All objects return from a non-generic factory will have the same type but since OP has an issue with to distinct types it's safe to say they are not the same however a generic factory won't solve that because there's no way to declare the type of the variable. What OP indeed has is a factory but that's the root of the problem more than a fix to the problem

Comment: the video about code reflection in [This C# guide](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/developer-training-with-programming-in-c#fbid=a3Q0QjWu3Uv) might be interesting to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you define a custom interface that encapsulates all the members you need to use, and implement it on both of your concrete types::

```
interface IMyInteface
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
}

class SpecificObject1 : IMyInterface { ... }
class SpecificObject2 : IMyInterface { ... }
```

And then declare your variable to be an instance of that interface:

```
IMyInterface genericObject;

if (!testFlag)
{
    genericObject = new SpecificObject1();
}

if (testFlag)
{
    genericObject = new SpecificObject2();
}

genericObject.FirstName = "Samuel";
genericObject.LastName = "Jackson";
```

But if that's not an option, you could use [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx), which will force any members to be evaluated at run time:

```
dynamic genericObject;

if (!testFlag)
{
    genericObject = new SpecificObject1();
}

if (testFlag)
{
    genericObject = new SpecificObject2();
}

genericObject.FirstName = "Samuel";
genericObject.LastName = "Jackson";
```

Answer (score 1):

If both `SpecificObject1` and `SpecificObject2` share similar properties, you could add an interface for them. You could then declare `genericObject` as the interface type and assign the concrete type later:

```
public interface SomeInterface
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class SpecificObject1 : SomeInterface
{
    // Implementation Details
}

public class SpecificObject2 : SomeInterface
{
    // Other Implementation Details
}
```

You would then be able to use them in the following manner:

```
SomeInterface genericObject;

genericObject = testFlag ? new SpecificObject2() : new SpecificObject1();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move all of the common members to a common base class or interface, then declare the variable as that type.

Answer (score 0):

If your types, you are going to assign later, are completely unrelated to each other and mainly have different set of methods to execute, [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) could be your choice of preference in this case.

In other cases, use standard `OOP` techniques, like *inheritance* and *polymorphism* to achieve what you are talking about.